# For loop for specific rows

Tags: r, for-loop, grepl

How would I remove some  job titles from the data frame (like below) FROM specific LOB? E.g. I want to keep **Technology manager** in LOB4 and I don't need **technology sales** in LOB2. When I execute the code below it removes titles from the entire data frame.

Is there any way to do this?

```
LOB     Title
LOB1    sales rep
LOB2    technology sales
LOB2    receptionist
LOB3    Web Designer
LOB4    Technology Manager



 for (i in c("(?=.*technology)", "(?=.*designer)")) {

    del <- grepl(i, data[data$LOB == "LOB1" | data$LOB == "LOB2",2], perl = T, ignore.case = T)

    data <- data[!del, ]
 }
```

Comment: "don't need technology sales in LOB1" - "technology sales" is in a row with LOB2. Did you mean that? Please confirm or edit.

Comment: Correct. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not working because the `grepl` statement is returning a vector with length of three that is then used to subset a `data.frame` with five rows.  A `for` loop is also probably not needed and any of the following will drop technology sales in LOB2:

```
data[!grepl("(?=.*(technology|designer))", data$Title, perl = TRUE), ]
data[!data$Title == "technology sales", ]
data[!data$Title %in% c("technology sales", "job2 to drop"), ]
data[-2, ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just gave an example of what I'm trying to do. The reason why I'm using for loop is because my database is over 1M jobs and the list of keywords that I need to exclude is ~500. I've been using this code to execute the code for the entire data frame and it works perfectly. However I also need to do the same for some specific records. I can also split the data frame, do the for loop, and then combine the data again, but I was thinking that there is more convenient way to do it. Hope it makes sense.